# Probably wrong syntax?

Tags: php

I am trying to insert some fields into a db by running a **.php** file, with no success.

It may be probably bad syntax, but since i am amateur in PHP, not really sure.

Could you guys help me correct my wrongs with this?

`mysql_query("DELETE FROM deleteme");` seems to be working fine,

but `mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'addme'` is not!

```
<?php  
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "localdb", "pass") or  
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db("localdb");  

mysql_query("DELETE FROM deleteme");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'addme' ('id', 'roleid', 'username', 'password', 'authmodule', 'authdata', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'signature', 'notes', 'template', 'language', 'loginattempts', 'supportdepts', 'ticketnotifications', 'homewidgets') VALUES
(3, 1, 'admin', 'af3c9', '', '', 'Admin', 'Administration', 'admin@email.com', '', '', 'typical', 'english', 0, '1,2,4', '', '')");

mysql_close($con);  
?>
```

Also Tried this, with no luck:

```
<?php  
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "localdb", "pass") or  
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db("localdb");  

mysql_query("DELETE FROM deleteme");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `addme` (`id`, `roleid`, `username`, `password`, `authmodule`, `authdata`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `signature`, `notes`, `template`, `language`, `loginattempts`, `supportdepts`, `ticketnotifications`, `homewidgets`) VALUES
(3, 1, 'admin', 'af3c9', '', '', 'Admin', 'Administration', 'admin@email.com', '', '', 'typical', 'english', 0, '1,2,4', '', '')");

mysql_close($con);  
?>
```

Comment: Always add the error message to the question.

Comment: Count mismatch in columns and values, also you are using single quotes for your table name

Comment: **Please** don't use `mysql_*` functions. the library is **deprecated**. Look into [**`PDO`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [**`MySQLi`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: @Johnathan Smith Can you print the error ?

Answer (score 2):

Table and column names should be surrounded with backticks, not quotes.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `addme` (`id`, `roleid`, `username`, `password`, `authmodule`, `authdata`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `signature`, `notes`, `template`, `language`, `loginattempts`, `supportdepts`, `ticketnotifications`, `homewidgets`) VALUES
(3, 1, 'admin', 'af3c9', '', '', 'Admin', 'Administration', 'admin@email.com', '', '', 'typical', 'english', 0, '1,2,4', '', '')");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks ` intsead of quotes '

```
INSERT INTO `addme` (`id`,....
```

Back ticks ` are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a [**MySQL reserved keyword**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

For more information see [**when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

And if you want to know where is Backticks is located on keyboard then see here [**how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows**](https://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows)

On the side note don't use mysql_* function. [WHY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)